# Using sp_spaceused on a temporary table

Tags: sql, sql-server, stored-procedures

All I want to do is search through a subscribers data (there are many more temp tables I want to check the data of) and just directly insert the results from `sp_spaceused` on a temp table into another temp table.
Then after it has finished counting all the data space and rows from about 100 different temp tables, to then output or calculate the results

```
SELECT DISTINCT
    t1.SubscriberGUID,
    t1.ItemGUID_Entity,
    t1.SubscriberID,
    t1.SubscriberRegionID,
    t1.SubscriberTypeID,
    t1.ID,
    t1.SubscriberNameFull,
    t1.SubscriberEmail,
    t1.SubscriberLogin,
    t1.SubscriberPassword,
    t1.Active,
    t1.DateCreated,
    t1.DateDeleted
INTO #Found_Subscriber
FROM (
        SELECT t100.*, ROW_NUMBER() OVER(Order BY (SELECT 1)) AS 'RowNumber'
        FROM
            #AllSubscribers t100
    ) AS t1
WHERE t1.RowNumber = @I

CREATE TABLE #FileSize
    (
        [name] NVARCHAR(128),
        [rows] INT,
        [reserved] VARCHAR(18),
        [data] VARCHAR(18),
        [index_size] VARCHAR(18),
        [unused] VARCHAR(18)
    )
    

INSERT INTO #FileSize exec sp_spaceused #Found_Subscriber
INSERT INTO #FileSize exec sp_spaceused #Found_SubscriberInfo
...
```

But this is not working. It throws an error saying:

> Msg 15009, Level 16, State 1, Procedure sp_spaceused, Line 120 [Batch Start Line 0]
> The object '#Found_Subscriber' does not exist in database 'd1' is invalid for this operation.

Comment: That row-number is just silly, you may as well use `TOP (@I)`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error message is telling you that you're calling `sp_spaceused` in the wrong database. Try:

```
EXEC tempdb.sys.sp_spaceused N'#Found_Subscriber';
```

Comment: Worked like a charm. Thanks. Also had to add [name] NVARCHAR(128) to the create table as I got an invalid column error after your change.